# Prove that $\sigma \mapsto A_\sigma $ is a group homomorphism $S_n\to GL_n(\mathbb R)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

For $\sigma \in S_n$, let $A_\sigma $ the matrix associated de the linear map $\lambda_\sigma  :\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ defined by $\lambda (x_1,...,x_n)=(x_{\sigma (1)},...,x_{\sigma (n)}).$ Prove that $\varphi :S_n\to GL_n(\mathbb R)$ defined by $$\varphi (\sigma )=A_\sigma .$$
is a group homomorphism. Describe the action on $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ of $S_n$ induced by $\varphi $. I recall that $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ are the $n\times n$ invertible matrix and $S_n$ is the group of permutation of $\{1,...,n\}$.

---

**Q1)** For the group homomorphism, let $\sigma ,\tau\in S_n$. So indeed $$\varphi ( \sigma )\varphi (\tau)(x_1,...,x_{n})=\varphi (\sigma )(x_{\tau(1)},...,x_{\tau(n)})=(x_{\sigma \circ\tau(1)},...,x_{\sigma \circ \tau(n)})=\varphi (\sigma \circ \tau)(x_1,...,x_n).$$

But I don't understand why as follow it's wrong : set $(y_1,...,y_n)=(x_{\tau(1)},...,x_{\tau(n)})$. Then $$\varphi (\sigma )\varphi (\tau)(x_1,...,x_n)=\varphi (\sigma )(x_{\tau(1)},...,x_{\tau(n)})=\varphi (\sigma )(y_1,...,y_n)=(y_{\sigma (1)},...,y_{\sigma (n)}).$$

And since $y_{i}=x_{\tau(i)}$ for all $i$ we have that $y_{\sigma (i)}=x_{\tau(\sigma (i))}$, and thus
$$\varphi (\sigma )\varphi (\tau)(x_1,...,x_n)=(x_{\tau\circ\sigma (1)},...,x_{\tau\circ\sigma (n)})=\varphi (\tau\circ \sigma )(x_1,...,x_n).$$
I can see that the last argument is not correct, but I don't understand what's wrong. Any idea ?

---

**Q2)** What means *Describe the action on $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ of $S_n$ induced by $\varphi $.* ? Would it be : it permute row and column of $A$ ?

Comment: it is not true;  $\lambda_\sigma(x)$ should be $(x_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma^{-1}(n)})$. Then your reasoning will show the desired property.

Answer (score 2):

I think I disagree with the question as stated. I claim that your first argument is incorrect, and that your second argument proves that the given map is not a group homomorphism. A slight modification gives what I think is the correct map.

First of all, I'd like to say in words what I think the given map $\varphi$ does:

> $\varphi(\sigma)$ takes the tuple $(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$, and for each $i$, moves the element in position $\sigma(i)$ to position $i$.

Now, to address argument 1. I disagree with the statement

$$\varphi (\sigma )(x_{\tau(1)},...,x_{\tau(n)})=(x_{\sigma \circ\tau(1)},...,x_{\sigma \circ \tau(n)}).$$

The definition of the map in words makes it clear that $\varphi(\sigma)$ should put in position $i$ the element in position $\sigma(i)$ from its argument. This is clearly the element $x_{\tau(\sigma(i))}$.

You may counter by saying "Well we defined $\varphi(\sigma)$ to map $x_{i} \mapsto x_{\sigma(i)}$. So we just apply $\sigma$ to the index. How is that wrong?". The reason is that that sentence does not properly define a function. To take an example, consider the case $n=3$ and the permutation $(1 2 3)$. Clearly, the definitions agree:

$$\varphi((123))(x_1,x_2, x_3) = (x_2,x_3,x_1)$$
So, $$A_{(123)} = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0}.$$
But what if we labelled the variables differently? What is $\varphi((123))(x_2,x_1,x_3)$? Well, we simply swapped two variables, so it should be $(x_1, x_3, x_2)$, which is what the wordy definition predicts. If we follow our more recent definition, however,

$$\varphi((123))(x_2,x_1, x_3) = (x_{\sigma(2)}, x_{\sigma(1)}, x_{\sigma(3)}) = (x_3, x_2, x_1)$$

I hope it is therefore clear that the definition leading to argument 1 cannot be correct, and that is where the argument fails. On the other hand I think your second argument is good: we therefore have the property

$$\varphi(\sigma \circ \tau) = \varphi(\tau) \circ \varphi(\sigma)$$

which is *not* a group homomorphism. However, as is pointed out in the comments, the related map $\psi(\sigma) = \varphi(\sigma^{-1})$ *is* a group homomorphism:

$$\psi(\sigma \circ \tau) = \varphi(\tau^{-1} \circ \sigma^{-1}) = \varphi(\sigma^{-1}) \circ \varphi(\tau^{-1}) = \psi(\sigma) \circ \psi(\tau).$$

As for describing the action, I suggest you work through an example. It permutes the *rows* but not the columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand why $\varphi ((123))(x_{2},x_1,x_3)$ should be $(x_1,x_3,x_2)$ ?

Comment: @user841366 It's a principle of substitutability. If I make a substitution on the LHS (in this case, "swap $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$"), then I should be able to preserve equality by making that substitution on the RHS.